# Bash pipe arguments does not seem to pass through

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not a very skilled linux user and I'm trying to make an automation for vscode such that I can open all the files with diff in them in vscode. My current suggestion is:

```
git diff master...[BRANCH_NAME] --name-only |code -r
```

The first part `git diff master...[BRANCH_NAME] --name-only` works perfectly fine giving:

```
src/components/LeftDrawerMenu/TaskForm/index.js
src/services/util.js
```

But the `code -r` does not registering the output as input. It runs as if there where no arguments.

I want the following:

```
code -r src/services/util.js src/components/LeftDrawerMenu/TaskForm/index.js
```

But

```
code -r src/services/util.js 
code -r src/components/LeftDrawerMenu/TaskForm/index.js
```

would also give the desired outcome. What do I do wrong?

Comment: `git diff master...[BRANCH_NAME] --name-only | xargs -d '\n' code -r`

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very welcome to @konsolebox to make it into an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that a pipe for different lines of output might not be handled correctly. Did you already try this:

```
code -r $(git diff master...[BRANCH_NAME] --name-only)
```

Comment: _grumble_. Not that this doesn't work in the simple case, but unquoted command substitution has a bunch of generally-unwanted behaviors (glob expansion, word-splitting on IFS); better to read into an array with `readarray -t myarray < <(...)`, `mapfile-t myarray < <(...)` or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a myarray < <(... && printf '\0')` and then expand that array.

Comment: Even better would be `git diff master...BRANCH_NAME --name-only | xargs -d $'\n' code -r`, which works right (by splitting into multiple `code` invocations) even when the list of names is too long to fit on a single command line.